# Updating an existing user does not work in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

when I try to update my database to change the location of an existing user, I receive the text in an echo which is desired but the details of a user are not changed.
Here is my code - server details have been removed on purpose for privacy.

```
{
     $server = ''; 
     $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>""); 
     $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 
     echo "Connected successfully";
     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $location = $_POST['location'];
     $dateAndTime = date('d-m-y h:i a', time());
     $selection_query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";

     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $selection_query, array($username));
     if (sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) == 0) 
     {
     echo "Username does not exist.";
     }
     else
     {

     $updateUserQuery = "UPDATE users SET location='$location' datetime='$dateAndTime' where username='$username'";
     sqlsrv_query($conn, $updateUserQuery);

     echo $username;
     echo "'s location has been successfully updated to ";
     echo $location;
     echo " at ";
     echo $dateAndTime;
     echo ".";
     }

     sqlsrv_close($conn);

         }
```

Comment: Try adding sqlsrv_query($conn, $updateUserQuery) or die(sqlsrv_error());

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: `update location set location...`, something seems wrong about that, that is unless you actually have a table named `location` with a column named `location` inside of it. Yo dawg...

Comment: yeah i changed that now though it still doesn't edit information

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your code, you should check to make sure your connection exists before trying to do a query. Kinda like this:

```
// Create connection
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
echo "Connected successfully";
```

This is important b/c it might not be that your query is returning no results but that you don't have a connection at all.

Once you have that, change this line in your query

```
$selection_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' LIMIT 1";
```

Also following what Jay Blanchard said in the comments, this way of writing querys leaves you open for SQL Inchections.  This is a way for a user to write a query inside of your query that you wouldn't expect to run.  Kinda like "DROP All Tables" query.  Never good to allow.  Following his link is a good idea.

Comment: when entering the connection check, i just got this as a response
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Can you update your code so i can see what you changed?

Comment: Yep I have done now, it's just after the $conn =sqlsrv_connect where I added it

Comment: So what's the response you get?  do you get "Connection failed: " and an error?  or do you get "Connected successfully"?

Comment: No I dont think the if statement is working in my code as it just outputs connected successfully and acts as it previously was

Comment: you never changed your $selection_query string.  Take a look at my answer again for the correct one.  You can also try an easy static query on your connection to see if the connection is working.  That will narrow down your issue.

Comment: sorry i forgot to update that on here but I changed that string but it still doesn't change the database, though it is connected as it successfully checks the database if the username exists in the database

Comment: Lol, so i change the query again.  I added ticks to the table name and column name.  This helps mysql know that it's referencing a table or column in case you're using reserved names. I believe user is one of them.  And note, that they are ticks and not single quotes.

Comment: Look at question carefully, mysqli is not even tagged in the question this answer is blunty off

Comment: Sorry, I was searing you in the wrong direction.  I fixed my answer.

Comment: I tried the fixed selection query though that just fails the program and can not find the user that i search for, though the connection checking confirms it is connected

Comment: Try this: "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' LIMIT 1"

Comment: Have you fixed your issue?